# Actualizar la suma al hacer un filtro en datatables

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables, sum

necesito de su ayuda por favor, estoy utilizando Datatables donde ya he conseguido hacer las sumas de mis dos columnas (**ACOUNT y TOTAL**) pero cuando hago un filtro por usuario me gustaría que la suma se actualizara y sólo mostrara los datos sumados de ese usuario.
Para este proyecto estoy utilizando la librería **Sum()** de datatables y para los estilos Bootstrap.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
          var table = $('#table_id').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            ordering: true,
            "pageLength": 10,
            "lengthMenu": [[5,10,50,-1], [5,10,50,"All"]],
            "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
            "autoWidth": false,
            "language":{
              "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.21/i18n/Spanish.json"
            }
          });

          //SUMA
          //ACOUNT
          var arrSalePriceOne = table.column(1).data().sum();
          $("#tblProfit").text((+arrSalePriceOne).toLocaleString('en-US'));
          //TOTAL
          var arrSalePriceTwo = table.column(2).data().sum();
          $("#sumados").text((+arrSalePriceTwo).toLocaleString('en-US'));

          // dropdown
          $('.filter-select').change(function(){
          table.column($(this).data('column'))
          .search($(this).val())
          .draw();
          });
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="text-center">
        <div class="row  mt-1">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="card text-center">
                    <div class="card-header p-1">
                        ACOUNT
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body p-1" style="background: #76b8da">
                        <h5>S/ <span id="tblProfit"></span></h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="card text-center">
                    <div class="card-header p-1">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                               TOTAL
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body p-1" style="background: #4ef3ae">
                    <h5>S/ <span id="sumados"></span></h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="card card-body">
        <div class="row mb-3 mt-2">
            <div class="col-2">
                <span><strong>User</strong></span>
                <select data-column="0" class="form-control filter-select">
                    <option value="">Todos</option>
                    <option value="Jose">Jose</option>
                    <option value="Carlos">Carlos</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>        
    <table id="table_id" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>User</th>
                <th>Account</th> 
                <th>Total</th> 
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Carlos</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>223.24</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Carlos</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Carlos</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>321</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jose</td>
                <td>200</td>
                <td>221</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jose</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>100</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Carlos</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>100</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jose</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>100</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Carlos</td>
                <td>14</td>
                <td>100</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Carlos</td>
                <td>26</td>
                <td>100</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jose</td>
                <td>76</td>
                <td>24</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jose</td>
                <td>86</td>
                <td>100</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jose</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>120</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.11.3/api/sum().js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Les agradecería mucho de su ayuda para resolver este requerimiento, alguna recomendación de como poder hacerlo  o quizá mi código implementado esta hecho de mala manera

Comment: DT trae todos los valores y luego los filtra ocultando los valores no deseados lo que hace imposible que puedas sumar los filtros ya que esos datos siguen ahí y por ende los sigue sumando

Comment: suponiendo que estas trayendo los datos de una BD y no son estáticos, podrías crear una función que se ejecute después de cargar tu tabla  esta función en lugar de traer los datos te deberá traer la suma de los mismos  según el filtro que le des a tu DT